How to clear db_table at the beginning of an experiment?
Is there a way to delete the rows of a db_table with the help of a function?
I tried using the following function in the "before simulation run" action:
clear()
reset()
But none of them worked, only within the db_table I have the option to delete entries/rows manually

Use deletFrom(myDbTable).execute(); before starting your experiment, see the help: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html#deleting-all-records-from-the-database-table
